# Getting "File on different device skipped: ..." error with tmpreaper inside Unbuntu 16.04 Docker container

Tags: php, docker

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 in a Docker container (FROM php:7.2.19-fpm) and trying to set up tmpreaper within cron to keep /tmp clean but I'm only ever getting the "File on different device skipped: ..." error

```
root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# touch /tmp/test.txt

root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# /usr/sbin/tmpreaper --test --verbose --showdeleted 1h /tmp

debug: Grace period is `3600' seconds.
debug: This is PID (2445) being run by UID (0), EUID (0).
debug: getcwd() is: /tmp
(PID 2445) Pretending to clean up directory `/tmp'.
debug: safe_chdir() : Before chdir(), `dirname' is inode `19302'.
debug: safe_chdir() : Before chdir(), `dirname' on device `110'.
debug: safe_chdir() : After chdir(), `dirname' is inode `19302'.
debug: safe_chdir() : After chdir(), `dirname' on device `110'.
debug: (PID 2446) Found directory entry `test.txt'.
File on different device skipped: `/tmp/test.txt'

root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# /usr/sbin/tmpreaper --verbose --showdeleted 1h /tmp
File on different device skipped: `/tmp/test.txt'

root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# ls -latr /tmp/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Nov 18 13:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Nov 19 19:59 test.txt
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 53248 Nov 19 20:00 .

root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# touch -a -t 201911191745.00 /tmp/test.txt
root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# ls -latr /tmp/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Nov 18 13:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Nov 19 19:59 test.txt
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 53248 Nov 19 20:01 .

root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# touch -c -t 201911191745.00 /tmp/test.txt
root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# ls -latr /tmp/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Nov 18 13:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Nov 19 17:45 test.txt
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 53248 Nov 19 20:01 .

root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# /usr/sbin/tmpreaper --verbose --showdeleted 1h /tmp
File on different device skipped: `/tmp/test.txt'


root@62fbdf27ec0f:/# stat /tmp/test.txt
  File: '/tmp/test.txt'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 2117399     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-11-19 17:45:00.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2019-11-19 17:45:00.000000000 +0000
Change: 2019-11-19 20:01:38.036390000 +0000
 Birth: -



cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: Not an answer, just a couple comments: I noticed inside docker that `/tmp` has fs type `overlay`; perhaps it doesn't work with `tmpreaper`? (due to [limited implementation of posix](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/)?) But not sure. The [source to tmpreaper](https://fossies.org/linux/tmpreaper/tmpreaper.c) shows it's making a system call & reporting different "device ID"; do you get the same error if starting `tmpreaper` from `/tmp`? (continued...)

Comment: I've used (and written) programs that use `/tmp` that will fail if the tmp file is deleted while the process is running. I'm not sure this overall is a great idea. Perhaps inspect a little more which processes are filling up `/tmp`, and see if that process can manage its use of `/tmp` better, or be restarted, or rollover, etc? eg., `sysdig`, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412112/7832